# Update column1 of csv1 to column5 in csv2 in python

Tags: python, csv

I am stuck with this for the whole day today, but basically what I am trying to achieve is that, I have csv1 with 2 columns, another csv2 with 5 columns.

CSV1

```
id1,10
id2,20
id3,22
id4,59
```

CSV2

```
id1,x,x,x,15
id11,x,x,x,32
id2,x,x,x,22
id3,x,x,x,42
id8,x,x,x,36
id4,x,x,x,47
```

Now I want to read from csv1, read id1 in csv1 and find the same id1 in csv2, then update csv2, with the value from csv1 for id1. Do the same for every row of csv1 and update csv2 based on the values. So updated csv2 would be

```
id1,x,x,x,10
id11,x,x,x,32
id2,x,x,x,20
id3,x,x,x,22
id8,x,x,x,36
id4,x,x,x,59
```

So far, I have the following code, but I am not sure how to update the column when writing back to csv2.

```
    with open(csv2, 'rU') as outCSV:
    outreader  = csv.reader(outCSV)
    outcol1 = []
    outcol5 = []

    for row in outreader:
        outcol1.append(row[0])
        outcol5.append(row[4])

    with open(inputcsv, 'rU') as inCSV:
    inreader = csv.reader(inCSV)

    for row in inreader:
        incol1 = row[0]
        incol2 = row[1]
        for i, name in enumerate(outcol1):  
            if incol1 == name:
                outcol5[i] = incol2

    print outcol5 #The updated column list.
```

So now, how can I write back this list which is the updated column to csv2. If I use the write rows, it writes the entire column, but doesn't update the column. Any help is appreciated. Thanks